# Como usar Record Linkage Toolkit para comparar un Vector?

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente código

```
 *dfA = pd.read_csv(args.file,index_col="Full_url",sep=",",engine='c',skipinitialspace=True, encoding='utf-8',dtype={ "City": object,"Country": object,"State": object,"Email": object,"Identifier": object,"Family": object,"Given": object,"Prefix": object,"Suffix": object,"Phone": object}) 

indexer = rl.Index()
indexer.add(Full())
candidate_links = indexer.index(dfA)
compare_cl = rl.Compare()

compare_cl.exact('Identifier', 'Identifier', label='Identifier')
compare_cl.string('City', 'City', method='jarowinkler', threshold=0.85, label='City')
compare_cl.string('Country', 'Country', method='jarowinkler', threshold=0.85, label='Country')
compare_cl.string('State', 'State', method='jarowinkler', threshold=0.85, label='State')
compare_cl.string('Email', 'Email', method='damerau_levenshtein', threshold=0.80, label='Email')
compare_cl.string('Family', 'Family', method='jarowinkler', threshold=0.80, label='Family')
compare_cl.string('Given', 'Given', method='jarowinkler', threshold=0.80, label='Given')
compare_cl.string('Prefix', 'Prefix', method='jarowinkler', threshold=0.80, label='Prefix')
compare_cl.string('Suffix', 'Suffix', method='jarowinkler', threshold=0.80, label='Suffix')
compare_cl.exact('Phone', 'Phone', label='Phone')


features = compare_cl.compute(candidate_links, dfA)*
```

Sin embargo, **Tengo un problema porque la columna 'Family' es un vector de nombres con una longitud variable**.
Por ejemplo un registro puede ser: `Family=Daniel||Alex||John||Felix`

Los item en el vector son separados por "||". **¿Puedo comparar las columnas 'Family' como vector? ¿Cómo indico el carácter de separación?**

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido Daniel, deberías [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/245616/edit) tu pregunta y traducirla a castellano, estás en **SO en Español** y las preguntas publicadas en otros idiomas terminan cerradas.

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad de StackOverflow en español, para realizar una pregunta aquí si que sea cerrada, traducela al castellano